# PayPal configuration Error iOS SDK - payPayServicemanager : unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I am trying to implement PayPal integration in iOS application.
**The app works fine while testing in device connected to XCode.** But when I try with to build app downloaded from TestFlight, it gives me this type of error:

> -[PayPalPaymentViewController payPalServiceManager]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

So it seems like work perfect with direct build in device, while not working with beta test from testflight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

> So it seems like work perfect with direct build in device, while not working with beta test from test flight.

Strange indeed!

@Paras, did you carry out the following step from [this section of our integration instructions](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#if-you-dont-use-cocoapods-then)?

> In your project's **Build Settings** (in the `TARGETS` section, not the `PROJECTS` section):
>       add `-lc++ -ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags`

Comment: Yes, I have add all needs libraries. But now the issue is solved by integrate latest SDK 2.9.0. Thank you.